# PHPMailer Authentication fails for some emails

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer for sending emails for an application hosted on aws server,and smtp host used is smtp.gmail.com.It's working for all emails i have created on gmail except one which is some thing like info@xxxx.com,which is also a gmail account and for which i can successfully login using credentials,i had set smtpdebug enabled and log shows as shown below

```
2018-04-30 12:14:24 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP         n5sm3109946pff.134 - gsmtp<br>
2018-04-30 12:14:24 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO 50.123.49.209<br> 
2018-04-30 12:14:24 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [50.123.49.209]250-SIZE    35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250    SMTPUTF8<br>
2018-04-30 12:14:24 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: STARTTLS<br> 
2018-04-30 12:14:24 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start    TLS<br>
2018-04-30 12:14:24 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO 50.123.49.209<br>
2018-04-30 12:14:24 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [50.123.49.209]250-SIZE    35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN    OAUTHBEARER    XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250    SMTPUTF8<br>
2018-04-30 12:14:24 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: AUTH LOGIN<br>
2018-04-30 12:14:24 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6<br>
2018-04-30 12:14:24 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: &lt;credentials    hidden&gt;<br> 2018-04-30 12:14:24 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334    UGFzc3dvcmQ6<br> 2018-04-30 12:14:24 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:    &lt;credentials hidden&gt;<br> 
2018-04-30 12:14:24 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 534-5.7.14    &lt;https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&amp;scc=1&amp;plt=AKgnsbuJ534-5.7.14    05Jvy6Ed1Z74_ltxq21C1R21LkDHQQxMNTnbtEujxy4pcVdYjChKwWT6R5utiNx7CR17xS534-5.7.14    Lz4uoRCWgOTjzsenrrLPg-5YNpbhxen-04ja1OP1NE16nqwNPMVkiWszrRwDT3WJM4YFCUdx534-5.7.14    Ue3YENnFdql9obazBzp1k2fm3kKk1cGjq5m27faTcO1txX4Y8oKs6Zl3Hjz40-mGcChHB_534-5.7.14    w10UYZM0Vj-X4MNeATZmrByU-LzhU&gt; Please log in via your web browser    and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14  Learn more at534 5.7.14     https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 n5sm3109946pff.134 -    gsmtp<br> 
2018-04-30 12:14:24 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed:    534-5.7.14    &lt;https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&amp;scc=1&amp;plt=AKgnsbuJ534-5.7.14    05Jvy6Ed1Z74_ltxq21C1weR21LkDHQQxMNTnbtEujxy4pcVdYjChKwWT6R5utiNx7CR17xS534-5.7.14    Lz4uoRCWgOTjzsenrrLPg-5YNpbhxen-04ja1OP1NE16nNPMVkiWszrRwDT3WJM4YFCUdx534-5.7.14    Ue3YENnFdql9obazBzp1k2fm3kKk1cGjq5m27faTcO1txX4Y8oKs6Zl3Hjz40-mGcChHB_534-5.7.14    w10UYZM0Vj-X4MNeATZmrByU-LzhU&gt; Please log in via your web browser    and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14  Learn more at534 5.7.14     https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 n5sm3109946pff.134 -    gsmtp<br> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>
2018-04-30 12:14:24 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
2018-04-30 12:14:24 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection n5sm3109946pff.134 - gsmtp<br>
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>
```

Comment: Does it always fail or does it sometimes fail?

Comment: @jordy it always fails for info@xxxx.com

Comment: Did you read the URL they gave you in that error? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for Google](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/). You need to ask Google support about why your login is failing

Comment: i had tried signing in to gmail app directly using those credentials and i can login successfully

Comment: Gmail requires additional auth steps when it sees a login from a new combination of mechanism and IP. If you read the troubleshooting guide it recommends going through their captcha unlock procedure to solve this problem.

Comment: @Synchro Yep,that solved the issue,thanks!!

Comment: @Machavity,It was specified in url in error log.I didn't notice it ,Thanks for pointing it !!!